# All Data not loading from CSV to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, csv

Only Integer Type data is loading/inserting from csv to Mysql.
Why not Character ?

Please give any suggestion....

This is Table...

```
create table numb(series int(10), network varchar(50), area varchar(50), state varchar(50));
```

and here is data loading command...

```
load data local infile "/home/aman007/telecomm.csv" into table numb(series, network, area, state);
```

This data is in CSV file...

```
series  network     area                    state
9999    VODAFONE    Delhi                   Delhi
9998    AIRTEL      Gujrat                  Gujrat
9997    AIRTEL      Uttar Pradesh (West)    Uttar Pradesh (West)
9996    AIRTEL      Haryana                 Haryana
9995    AIRTEL      Kerala                  Kerala
9994    AIRTEL      Tamil Nadu              Tamil Nadu
9993    AIRTEL      Madhya Pradesh          Madhya Pradesh
9992    IDEA        Haryana                 Haryana
9991    VODAFONE    Haryana                 Haryana
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'

Comment: i did but nothing happens....

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tab-separated values (TSV).

Try:

File: `/path/to/file/tsv/telecomm.csv`

```tsv
series  network area    state
9999    VODAFONE    Delhi   Delhi
9998    AIRTEL  Gujrat  Gujrat
9997    AIRTEL  Uttar Pradesh (West)    Uttar Pradesh (West)
9996    AIRTEL  Haryana Haryana
9995    AIRTEL  Kerala  Kerala
9994    AIRTEL  Tamil Nadu  Tamil Nadu
9993    AIRTEL  Madhya Pradesh  Madhya Pradesh
9992    IDEA    Haryana Haryana
9991    VODAFONE    Haryana Haryana
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `numb`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `numb` (
    ->   `series` INT(10),
    ->   `network` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   `area` VARCHAR(50),
    ->   `state` VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/tsv/telecomm.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `numb`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    ->   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 9  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `series`,
    ->   `network`,
    ->   `area`,
    ->   `state`
    -> FROM
    ->   `numb`;
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| series | network  | area                 | state                |
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   9999 | VODAFONE | Delhi                | Delhi                |
|   9998 | AIRTEL   | Gujrat               | Gujrat               |
|   9997 | AIRTEL   | Uttar Pradesh (West) | Uttar Pradesh (West) |
|   9996 | AIRTEL   | Haryana              | Haryana              |
|   9995 | AIRTEL   | Kerala               | Kerala               |
|   9994 | AIRTEL   | Tamil Nadu           | Tamil Nadu           |
|   9993 | AIRTEL   | Madhya Pradesh       | Madhya Pradesh       |
|   9992 | IDEA     | Haryana              | Haryana              |
|   9991 | VODAFONE | Haryana              | Haryana              |
+--------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I did same but not getting this result.you did same and got result and i did but not get this result.
Is there any version issue ?
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3